# How to add files to a ZIP archive without deleting everything in it

Tags: python, zip

So, whenever I'd add a file to the ZIP archive, it would paste it in, but delete everything previously added.
Example: 

`zf = zipfile.ZipFile(os.getenv('localappdata') + '/test.zip')`

`zf.write(os.getenv('appdata') + '/test.txt')`

Like I said, it would paste the test.txt and delete everything else in the .zip

Comment: You need to pass "a" argument for it to append and not write/overwrite

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a file to a zip file retaining its content, you should open the zip file in **append mode** by adding `'a'` to its parameters:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(os.getenv('localappdata') + '/test.zip', 'a')
```